# Matching a "." in java

Tags: java, regex

I have the below string

```
String srcString = "String1.String2.String3";
```

I want to split "srcString" on "."

Using srcString.split(".") is matching all the characters.

What is the regex to match a "." ?

Comment: `String.split("\\.")` It's a regex, not a string literal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In regex [dot](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) is [special character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special) representing *any character* except line separator (to also make it match line separators use `Pattern.DOTALL` flag).

Anyway, use `split("\\.")`

Explanation:

- to escape `.` we can add `\` before it so we end up with regex `\.`
- now since `\` is also special in string literal `" "` we also need to escape it there, so to express `\.` we need to write it as `"\\."`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `split("\\.")` as . (dot) is special character so use `\\` before .(dot)

Answer (score 0):

You could also call the function `org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.split(String, char)` of the library `commons-lang` [http://commons.apache.org/lang/][1]