# Java Split String Using Delimiter

Tags: java, android, split, stringtokenizer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Matching a “.” in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11396864/matching-a-in-java)

I have a String `1.2.4` which i want to split and get `2` to compare it with another String that i get.

I am trying to do the following

```
    StringTokenizer old_ver = new StringTokenizer(oldVersion, ".");
    int oldVer = Integer.parseInt(old_ver.nextToken());
    oldVer = Integer.parseInt(old_ver.nextToken());

    StringTokenizer new_ver = new StringTokenizer(newVersion, ".");
    int newVer = Integer.parseInt(new_ver.nextToken());
    newVer = Integer.parseInt(new_ver.nextToken());

    if (oldVer == newVer) {
        return true;
    }
```

IS there a better way to do it using `.Split()`

Comment: While you *can* use `split`, I'd personally use Guava's `Splitter` class.

Comment: @Swapnil performance wise

Comment: Can you edit your question so that people dont have to read through all the comments to understand it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, 1.2.1 would be "compatible" with 3.2.0, and this looks like a serious problem, regardless if you use `String.split` or not. Also, you do not need to parse version numbers into integers as you only compare for equality.

```
 StringTokenizer old_ver = new StringTokenizer(oldVersion, ".");
 StringTokenizer new_ver = new StringTokenizer(newVersion, ".");
 return (old_ver.nextToken().equals(new_ver.nextToken() && 
         old_ver.nextToken().equals(new_ver.nextToken() );
```

You can surely do with `String.split` as well:

```
   String [] oldV = String.split(oldVersion,"\\.");
   String [] newV = String.split(newVersion,"\\.");

   return oldV[0].equals(newV[0]) && oldV[1].equals(newV[1]);
```

The `String.split()` version seems slightly shorter but but for me it looks slightly more difficult to read because:

- It involves additional thinking step that dot (.) is a reserved char and must be escaped.
- "Next element and then following element" seems involving less thinking effort than "element at position 0 and then element at position 1".

It may pay to have some version comparator that first compares major, then intermediate and then minor parts of the version number the way that we could have the tests like "1.2.4 or later".

Comment: wow i didnt think of that version change :P any idea how to handle this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361586/android-pushing-updates-on-play-store

Answer (score 6):

The problemis that in Regex "." is a single character. Hence, you need to escape it using "`\\.`"

Similarly, you can use

```
string.split("\\.");
```

**EDIT:**

`split()` method of the `String` class uses `Pattern` and `Matcher` internally which is normally the API used for Regex in Java.

So there is no problem going with `split`.